# Factorial code does not return product of integer and all integers before it

Tags: python, range, factorial

Fill in the blanks to make the factorial function return the factorial of n. Then, print the first 10 factorials (from 0 to 9) with the corresponding number. Remember that the factorial of a number is defined as the product of an integer and all integers before it. For example, the factorial of five (5!) is equal to 1x2x3x4x5=120. Also recall that the factorial of zero (0!) is equal to 1.

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for x in range(1,___):
        result = ___ * ___
    return ___

for n in range(___,___):
  print(n, factorial(n+1))
```

---

**What I came up with is below with the output**

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for x in range(0,10):
        result = result * x
    return x

for n in range(0,10):
  print(n, n*factorial(n+1))
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 9
2 18
3 27
4 36
5 45
6 54
7 63
8 72
9 81
```

Comment: In the loop you start multiplying with 0

Comment: Try `def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for x in range(2,n+1):
        result = result * x
    return result

for n in range(0,10):
    print(n, factorial(n))`

Comment: Three problems: you include `0` in the values being multiplied together; you ignore the value of `n` completely in the function; and you `return x` (the loop counter) instead of `result` (the product).

Comment: Start calculating at `2`, `1` would be useless and `0` will break it.

Comment: Please include your attempts to debug the program yourself, as mentioned in the posting guidelines.  If nothing else, insert some strategic `print` commands to track the data you're using.  One or two of those would have fixed at least two of the main problems in this program.

Comment: The following code:
`def factorial(n): result = 1 for x in range(2,n+1): result = result * x return result for n in range(0,10): print(n, factorial(n))` runs no results because `return result` doesn't return anything.

Comment: def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        result= result* i
    return result

print(factorial(4)) # should return 24
print(factorial(5)) # should return 120

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with you `factorial` funciton:

```py
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for x in range(0, 10):
        result = result * x
    return x
```

You always do 10 multiplications for every `n`.
But, for example, for `3!` you will need just 3 multiplications, because `3! = 1 * 2 * 3 = 6`. You can see that for every `n` you will need `n` multiplications. And you can admit that we always start our multiplications form 1, not 0.
That's why your `for` loop will be like this:

```
for x in range(1, n + 1):
    result = result * x
```

Also in your code, you return `x`. It will always be equal to 9 in your code. Because it will be the last value of the `range(0, 10)`.

That's why you got these answers:

```
0 0 # 0 * 9
1 9 # 1 * 9
2 18 # 2 * 18
```

Also, you don't need to multiply by anything the result of the function. Just calling `factorial(num)` will return the correct result.

Comment: The code: 
`def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for x in range(1, n + 1):
        result = result * x
    return x


for n in range(1,10):
    print(n, factorial(n))`

Returns the following:

`1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9`

Comment: @susanf, as I mentioned:

>Also in your code, you return x. It will always be equal to 9 in your code. Because it will be the last value of the range(0, 10).


You need to do `return result` at the end of the function instead of the `return x`.